# Find the exact error record

Tags: sql-server

Sometimes we have to debug a stored procedure getting data from multiple tables that is a select statement having many joins with many tables and we get an error message as like Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Sql server gives me line number but it is not that helpful

Can anybody tell me how can I find a particular record which is causing me the above error

there are ways like get data from first join and then keep on adding the other joins till you got the table which is causing the issue

It is very long process

is there any way to find that record causing error

Comment: We need to see your code. There would be a `CONVERT` statement somewhere in the code. The column being converted is the culprit

Answer (score 1):

May be [**ISDATE Function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) should help you.

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value;
>   otherwise, 0.

To filter out the Invalid records use this query

```
select * from tablename where ISDATE(datecolumn)=0
```

It will be better if show your code that generated the error